# find verified status for a list of facebook pagenames

Tags: excel, vba, facebook-fql

I have 782 Facebook page links with their page names in an excel file. I want to find out how many of them are verified by FB. So I started to find a solution. I got few articles that were not relevant to my question and those who were relevant had limited information or something that I could not understand. After searching a bit more I have some home wrote a code given below but it does not echo the verified status. Also how can I use it if I need to check 782 pagenames. Please help...

```
<?php
function verified($pagename){
    // Query in FQL
    $fql  = "SELECT is_verified";
    $fql .= " FROM page WHERE username = '$pagename'";
    $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql);

    // Facebook Response is in JSON
    $response = file_get_contents($fqlURL);
    return json_decode($response);
}

$fb = verified('nokia');
echo $fb[0]->is_verified;

?>
```

EDIT:
More Info:
I searched for it and found that it can be done using fql and api v21 both

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT is_verified FROM page WHERE username=nokia

nokia/?fields=is_verified
```

Here is the documentation

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/
```

I want help in getting the code repaired and what do i need to do if I have to check 782 pagenames. Presently I have put all those links in mysql myTable table and trying out things. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done via excel vba

```
    Function Status(sPagename As String) As Boolean


      Static oHTTP As WinHttpRequest
      sURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT is_verified FROM page WHERE username=" & "'" & sPagename & "'"

      If oHTTP Is Nothing Then Set oHTTP = New WinHttpRequest


      On Error GoTo Oops
      With oHTTP
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .Send

        If InStr(.ResponseText, "true") > 0 Then Status = True


        Exit Function
      End With


    Oops:
      Status = False
    End Function
```

It requires a reference to Microsoft WinHTTP Services to be added

Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the verified status is not in the page table (anymore), it does not show up in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page

Also, FQL is deprecated and does not work in newer Apps anymore, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

I think there is no way to check if a page is verified, unfortunately. The only way how this may be possible with FQL is by using an App created before April 21st, 2010. That is, before v2.1 came out, without FQL.

Comment: I edited my question. verified status is very much in the page table according to the old link and if FQL is deprecated, how can i achieve my desired result? Please help. Thanks

Comment: what old link? i don´t see the verified status - unless you mean the old FQL link, that´s only available if you search for FQL in the docs.

Comment: about how this may be possible, see the last part of my answer - with an older app.

Comment: and fql is NOT available in v2.1 anymore. see changelog.

Comment: I hope you read my edited part. I understand fql is not avb in v2.1 By old link i meant the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/ i get a json object when i go to this url https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT is_verified FROM page WHERE username=nokia and to get it via 2.1 explorer I can do it via nokia/?fields=is_verified

Comment: keep in mind that the api explorer may work a bit different. always test with a real app if possible. if fql still works somehow with v2.1 then it may be a bug.

Comment: Thanks luschn, forget the fql part... if this code needs to be modified taking into consideration v2.1 then what changes do i need to make? How can I run the function on my 700+ pagenames if I have all such pagenames in a database?

Comment: you can´t modify it for v2.1, it is just not possible anymore. btw, always add an access token to every api call.